# How to use defined variable in Where clause

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Defining and selecting variable works just fine in Oracle SQL Developer.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE=english; -- First day of week
--DEFINE SUMMER_START_DT = TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('03-24-2022', 'MM-DD-YYYY'),'yyyymmdd')
DEFINE SUMMER_START_DT = TO_CHAR(NEXT_DAY(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR('01/03/' || (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-1 + level) || '02:00:00'),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) - INTERVAL '7' DAY, 'SUNDAY'),'yyyymmdd') FROM DUAL CONNECT BY level <=1 
SELECT &SUMMER_START_DT;
```

[image]

But I get an error when trying to use the variable in Select statement using it as filter in the Where clause.

```
SELECT a.* FROM TRADE a WHERE TO_CHAR(a.TRADE_DATE_TIME,'yyyymmdd') = &SUMMER_START_DT;
```

I get the error "SQL command not properly ended"
[image]

Hope someone can help me. Thanks

Kind regards

Soren Sig Mikkelsen

Comment: your first part doesn't work either https://dbfiddle.uk/F34wM7NE

Comment: Okay that suprise me. I have just added a screenshot in my question showing it works when I run it in Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: [Substitution variables](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/using-scripts-in-SQL-Plus.html#GUID-68AC9FF2-B92A-48D1-9699-133D47F8DDC1) work in Oracle's SQL\*Plus, SQL Developer and SQLcl tools, and some other clients support them for compatibility. But they are a client thing, not part of the SQL, even within Oracle. db<>fiddle doesn't recognise them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You substitution variable includes `from dual`, which is OK when you just prepend `select` in your first example; but in the second you end up with two `from` clauses:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM TRADE a
WHERE TO_CHAR(a.TRADE_DATE_TIME,'yyyymmdd') =
  TO_CHAR(NEXT_DAY(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR('01/03/' || (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-1 + level) || '02:00:00'),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) - INTERVAL '7' DAY, 'SUNDAY'),'yyyymmdd')
FROM DUAL CONNECT BY level <=1
```

(You can see that in the generated column name/alias in the output grid; or `set verify on` and run as a script.)

If you really wanted to use that as the right-hand side of the filter then you could enclose it in parentheses:

```
SELECT a.* FROM TRADE a WHERE TO_CHAR(a.TRADE_DATE_TIME,'yyyymmdd') = (SELECT &SUMMER_START_DT);
```

which would become:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM TRADE a
WHERE TO_CHAR(a.TRADE_DATE_TIME,'yyyymmdd') =
  (
    SELECT TO_CHAR(NEXT_DAY(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR('01/03/' || (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-1 + level) || '02:00:00'),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) - INTERVAL '7' DAY, 'SUNDAY'),'yyyymmdd')
    FROM DUAL CONNECT BY level <=1
  )
```

But the `connect by` isn't doing anything here, so you can remove that; and if you remove `from dual` as well then you can run your first statement as:

```
SELECT &SUMMER_START_DT FROM DUAL;
```

and the second as it is.

You could simplify the calculation though. For a start you aren't using the time element, so you don't need to make it 2am; and you can truncate to the start of the year and add two months to get March 1st; as a string if that's really what you want:

```
to_char(next_day(last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY'), 2)) - 7, 'SUNDAY'), 'YYYYMMDD')
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8t0DtETt)

But you can keep it as a date; if you:

```
DEFINE SUMMER_START_DT = next_day(last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY'), 2)) - 7, 'SUNDAY')
```

then again you can do:

```
SELECT &SUMMER_START_DT FROM DUAL;
```

and your second query can be:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM TRADE a
WHERE a.TRADE_DATE_TIME >= &SUMMER_START_DT
AND a.TRADE_DATE_TIME < &SUMMER_START_DT + 1
```

which avoids converting *every* `TRADE_DATE_TIME` date value to a string to compare it, and allows an index on that date column to be used.

Comment: Hereby resolved. 
Many thanks to both of you. I am very grateful for your help ;-)